# Where can I find a list of merchants who accept bitcoins?

Tags: payment, websites, merchants, commerce

Is there a list of merchants who accept bitcoins?

Comment: I belive that this is covered by [Is there a list of established sites that have started accepting Bitcoin?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1257/is-there-a-list-of-established-sites-that-have-started-accepting-bitcoin) and [A list of trusted Bitcoin websites?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1968/a-list-of-trusted-bitcoin-websites). Agree?

Comment: @D.H.: The question is actually quite distinct from these two. One focuses on preestablished businesses, the other on recording merchants' reputation.

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld: Well, yes, but the first one already mentions the wiki trade page in the question and the second one overlaps with this one. I agree that the questions are not identical but I'm pretty sure that anything that turns up here will already be covered by one of the other questions. But, anyway, I will leave this question open unless others want to close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As well as the https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade page you could look at:

http://www.thebitcoinreview.com/

and

http://www.thebitcointrader.com/p/bitcoin-better-business-bureau.html

Both of these sites try to give some kind of rating or review but the data is limited at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

There are so many places A quick google search will yield many results But other than the main list on the wiki i think the following directories seemed pretty populated.

**'Official Lists'**

- [Exchanges](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Category%3aExchanges)
- [Local Directories](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Category%3aDirectories)
- [Marketing](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Category%3aMarketing)
- [Online & Real Business](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade)
- [Games & Gambling](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Category%3aGames)
- [Real World Shops map overlay](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Real_world_shops)
- [Donation Accepting Sites](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Donation-accepting_organizations_and_projects)

**Articles**

- [75 Places to Spend your Bitcoins](http://www.shopify.co.uk/blog/10480345-75-places-to-spend-your-bitcoins)
- [Online Stores Accepting Bitcoin](http://www.bitcointrading.com/forum/spend-bitcoins/online-stores-accepting-bitcoins/)
- [10 Places to spend Bitcooin in the UK (Telegraph)](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/news/10558191/Ten-places-where-you-can-spend-your-bitcoins-in-the-UK.html)
- [NASDAQ - What Companies Accept Bitcoin](http://www.nasdaq.com/article/what-companies-accept-bitcoin-cm323438)
- [FORBES - How to Use bitcoin to shop at Amazon, Home Depot, CVS and More](http://www.forbes.com/sites/clareoconnor/2014/02/17/how-to-use-bitcoin-to-shop-at-amazon-home-depot-cvs-and-more/)
- [The Guardian - Where can you spend Bitcoins](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2013/nov/25/where-can-you-use-bitcoins-brief-guide)
- [HONGKIAT - 20 Places to Spend Bitcoin](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/places-to-spend-bitcoins/)

**Directories**

- [BitPay Business Directory](https://bitpay.com/directory#/)
- [World Map Depicting Locations of Bitcoin Business](http://coinmap.org/)
- [Bitcoin Aware, Directory with some news Feeds](http://bitcoinaware.com/)
- [Team Bitcoin, Directory of educations resources, exchanges and merchants](http://www.teambitcoin.com/)
- [Spend Bitcoin - Directory with site reviews along side listings](https://spendbitcoins.com/places/)
- [The Bitcoin Review - Another directory including reviews of listings](http://www.thebitcoinreview.com/)
- [The Bitcoin List - A Categorized Directory Index](http://www.thebitcoinlist.com/)
- [Bitcoin Source - A fairly comprehensive directory of all things bitcoin](http://bitcoinsource.net/)
- [Bitcoin-Directory - A Still somewhat sparse Directory](http://bitcoin-directory.com/)
- [Shops4Bitcoin - Nothing Listed yet, but potentially a good future resource](http://www.shops4bitcoins.com/)
- [BTC Pages - A Clean designed directory with a reasonable number of listings](http://btcpages.com/)
- [Coin Made - Another fairly well populated directory](http://coinmade.org/)
- [Yellow Coins - Not many listings here yet](http://yellowcoins.com/bitcoin/Merchants/)
- [bitcoin dir - some good listings still could be more populated](http://bitcoindir.com/)

**Cryptostocks, IPO's, Profit Shares, and Equities**

- [CryptoStocks - A good all round offering of stocks etc available in the crypto Market place](https://cryptostocks.com/)
- [Havelock Investments - A reputable listing of IPO's available for Crypto, with stringent controls for registering an IPO etc](https://www.havelockinvestments.com/)
- [Bitcoin Bourse - A Bitcoin Exchange (currently 05/03/2013) offering some stocks on thier trading system as well as Crypto Trading](https://bitcoinbourse.eu/)
- [Crypto-Trade - Although Recently they seem to have had some kind of security Breach they do offer a variety of securities for Trade](https://crypto-trade.com/)
- [P2P Bitcoin Loans](https://btcjam.com)

**Some Places I spend My Bitcoin**

- [Scan.co.uk - UK based computer hardware Retailer](http://scan.co.uk)
- [Takeaway.com - Order Takeaway for Bitcoin (not all restaurants accept all BTC)](http://www.takeaway.com/)
- [Bitcoin Store - A good all round store US based so a killer on import Duty and Delivery was a little slow last time I ordered.  But shier customer Service was excellent](https://www.bitcoinstore.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the most comprehensive and well-known such list is at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade.

Answer (score 1):

Check http://coinmap.org this may be of help for you

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Bitcoin wiki (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade) has grown completely unwieldy and has many outdated / no-longer-working links.

[Coinmap](http://coinmap.org/) is a decent place if you're looking for "brick and mortar" businesses, and [spendabit.co](https://spendabit.co/) lists millions of products from a growing number of Bitcoin-enabled merchants (including the usual list -- Overstock.com, TigerDirect, etc).