# Where can I Buy any Single Pizza Using Bitcoins?

Tags: ecommerce, merchants

I would like to purchace this notorious Pizza that is talked about , I would like that the bitcoin not be a come-on for a coupon for a pizza, but an actual pizza that I can eat?
Can I buy a Pizza directly and wholey without any additional cash or credit added  with a Bitcoin?  or only a virtual emptyness in my virtual stomach?

Comment: Related question: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2089/where-can-i-go-to-find-a-list-of-merchants-who-accept-bitcoins

Answer (score 1):

You could just use [pizzaforcoins](http://pizzaforcoins.com/).

Comment: conversion site with come-on.  I get Spam from them, I wanted a Pizza ""•We may periodically send promotional emails about new products, special offers or other information which we think you may find interesting using the email address which you have provided.""

Comment: oh i see didn't know that...well my offer still stands lol

Comment: And you still  deserve an up-vote, if only I could up-vote.  Because you did indeed find a place where I could convert hours and hours of GPU use into a delivered pizza.  Which sounds rather tempting, even with years of unwanted spam added to the mix. :-)  Uhh THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know a local restaurant that accepts bitcoins directly, you will have to use a service, such as pizzaforcoins, which will basically accept your bitcoins and then order the for you.

There are a few restuarants, such as lean crusts in Brooklyn which directly accepts bitcoin, so you should google for restaurants in your area.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are some order-services like [Foodler](http://foodler.com) which allow you to pay with bitcoin for food. Whether there is a brick and mortar store in your vicinity that directly accepts bitcoin for pizza is hard to tell without knowing your location.

You could try to see by looking through one of the lists of places that accept bitcoin such as found at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade#Consumables or [spendbitcoins.com](https://www.spendbitcoins.com/places/)