# Where can I get a list of places I can use my Bitcoins?

Tags: trading, merchants, commerce

I am new to Bitcoin and I'm trying to understand how it works and how I can make it work for me.

So, let's say I travel often to different Spanish speaking countries in South America and Spain. How can I acquire a list of all the vendors, merchants, services, etc. that use the Bitcoin exchange in all these areas to avoid using the banking system of "money transfer?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I go to find a list of merchants who accept bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2089/5406)

Answer (score 2):

You can try [CoinMap](http://coinmap.org). It's the largest database of physical locations that accept Bitcoin.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a list here https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Real_world_shops . It has a good list as well.