# Can I use Bitcoin elsewhere except in the deep web?

Tags: payment, merchants, adoption

I really like the idea of having an universal online currency and I wanted to know if I can use it in the 'surface web'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use bitcoins in many places. There are Bitcoin exchanges where you may exchange your coins for USD or vice-versa. You can also use them on various websites like Newegg for example.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of applications. Bitcoin is e.g. used for

- donations, e.g. [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/donate)
- online-shops for digital goods, e.g. vpn, web hosting, mail servers, [mp3s](https://libertymusicstore.net/), [computer games](http://www.greenmangaming.com/)
- mail-order companies, e.g. [Overstock](http://overstock.com)
- booking flights and hotels, e.g. on Expedia
- remittances
- [brick and mortar stores](https://coinmap.org/welcome/)

You can find a more complete overview on the question [Where can I find a list of merchants who accept bitcoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2089/5406)

Answer (score 0):

With the Shift card, you can spend Bitcoin anywhere Visa is accepted.

https://www.shiftpayments.com/

Answer (score -1):

Yes! Of course! Websites like Overstock.com accept bitcoin.